# python pandas dataframes add column depending on values other 2 col

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I finally got to a message that I expected could solve my problem. I have two columns in a dataFrame (height, upper) with values either 1 or 0. The combination of this is 4 elements and with them I am trying to create a third column containing the 4 combinations, but I cannot figure out what is going wrong, My code is as follows:

```
def quad(clasif):
    if (raw['upper']==0 and raw['height']==0):
        return 1
    if (raw['upper']==1 and raw['height']==0):
        return 2
    if (raw['upper']==0 and raw['height']==1):
        return 3
    if (raw['upper']==1 and raw['height']==1):
        return 4

raw['cuatro']=raw.apply(lambda clasif: quad(clasif), axis=1)
```

I am getting the following error:

> 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', u'occurred at index 0'

if someone could help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that upper and height can only be 0 or 1, you can rewrite this as a simple addition:

```
raw['cuatro'] = 1 + raw['upper'] + 2 * raw['height']
```

---

The reason you see this error is because `raw['upper'] == 0` is a Boolean series, which you can't use *and*... See the ["gotcha" section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas).

I think you're missing the fundamentals of apply, when passed the Series `clasif`, your function should do something with `clasif` (at the moment, the function body makes no mention of it).

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the function to `apply`.

```
import pandas as pd

def quad(clasif):
    if (clasif['upper']==0 and clasif['height']==0):
        return 1
    if (clasif['upper']==1 and clasif['height']==0):
        return 2
    if (clasif['upper']==0 and clasif['height']==1):
        return 3
    if (clasif['upper']==1 and clasif['height']==1):
        return 4
​
raw = pd.DataFrame({'upper': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'height': [0, 1, 0, 1]})
raw['cuatro']=raw.apply(quad, axis=1)

print raw

height  upper   cuatro
0   0   0   1
1   1   0   3
2   0   1   2
3   1   1   4
```

Andy Hayden's answer is better suited for your case.